# Getting right-click working in Chrome and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

This script is working on "ctrl c". I need work on right click menu (Chrome context menu).

I have added the snippet of my code for your reference. Would someone suggest some solution to the given problem?

My code:

```
var linkAddress = $('<span id="copylAddress" style="display: inline-block;" 
/>');
$('body').append(linkAddress);
// This is a DOM element that has to be selectable but not visible to 
anybody
linkAddress.css({position: 'absolute', left:'-9999em'});

var previousCaretPosition = -1;

COPYL_DEBUG = false;

function write_to_console(text) {
    if (COPYL_DEBUG)
        console.log(text);
}

function selectElement(el) {
    // Check if anything is currently selected, if so backup
    if (window.getSelection().rangeCount > 0) {
    previousCaretPosition = document.activeElement.selectionStart;
}
write_to_console("Previous cursor position: " + previousCaretPosition);
var range = document.createRange();

write_to_console("Selecting element " + el);
write_to_console("el[0] is " + el[0]);
range.selectNodeContents(el[0]);
write_to_console("Range: " + range);

write_to_console("Window selection range count before: " + 
window.getSelection().rangeCount);
if (window.getSelection().rangeCount > 0) {
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
write_to_console("Window selection range count now: " + 
window.getSelection().rangeCount);

write_to_console("Active Element: " + document.activeElement);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
write_to_console("Window selection range count after: " + 
window.getSelection().rangeCount);
}

function clearLinkAddress() {
if (linkAddress.text()) {
    linkAddress.text("");
    linkAddress.blur();
    write_to_console("Cleared linkAddress");

    write_to_console("window.getSelection: " + window.getSelection());
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
if (previousCaretPosition != -1)
{
    document.activeElement.selectionStart = previousCaretPosition;
    write_to_console("Previous cursor position set: " + 
document.activeElement.selectionStart);
}

write_to_console("Current selection: " + window.getSelection().toString());
}

$(function() {
// The code attaches itself to all anchor elements
$("html").on("mouseenter", "td", function(){
    // Everytime the user hovers (enters) a link
    if(window.getSelection().toString()) {
        write_to_console("Something is already selected. Don't do 
anything.");
    } else {
        write_to_console("Nothing is selected.");

        linkAddress.text($(this).prop('title'));
        write_to_console("linkAddress: " + linkAddress.text());
        selectElement(linkAddress);
    }

    write_to_console("Current Selection: " + 
window.getSelection().toString());
}).on("mouseleave", "td", function(){
        // Every time the user leaves a link
        write_to_console("Leaving link.");
        clearLinkAddress();
    });

$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
    clearLinkAddress();
});

});
```

Comment: What did the warning say when you tried to post the question? Was it encouraging to add the same paragraph over and over again?

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. @Teemu

Comment: Yep, "more details" doesn't mean repeating the same detail ...

Comment: @Teemu I am new on stackoverflow. I failed to open the subject, sorry.

Comment: the script is working on `Ctrl + c`??? I don't get what you wanna ask at all bro

Comment: @messerbill this script copies an object. Triggered by ctrl + c. I want to work on the chrome context menu

Comment: sorry i really don't get it....what's wrong with the chrome's context menu? Please create a jsfiddle for better demonstration

Comment: @messerbill this is chrome extension js file. Pressing ctrl + c copies the selected object. I want work on chrome right click menu, not with ctrl + c.

Comment: From what I gather, pressing `ctrl c` works as OP wanted but using the right click context menu `copy` it does not work and OP wants that to work

Comment: Write in ask that you need use context menu only! . Your ask is  not correct.

Comment: Yes i want use context menu for there functions.